# Reactive Native: place view bellow another centered view

Tags: layout, react-native

I used to do this a lot using Android relative layouts:

```
 +-----------+ 
 |           |<- parent view
 |           |
 |  +-----+  |
 |  |     | <--- centered 
 |  |     |  |   child view
 |  +-----+  |
 |   [XXX] <---- view positioned
 |           |   bellow centered
 +-----------+   child view
```

Is it possible to achieve the same in react-native?

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar today like this:

```
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <View style={{
                        height: 350, 
                        backgroundColor: "blue"
                    }}>

                    <View style={{
                        backgroundColor: "red", 
                        height: 100, 
                        width: 100, 
                        position: "absolute", 
                        top: "50%", 
                        left: "50%", 
                        marginLeft: -50, // Half the width of this child
                        marginTop: -50 // Half the height of this child
                    }}>
                        <Text>Hello...</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={{ 
                        backgroundColor: "green", 
                        height: 30, 
                        width: 100, 
                        position: "absolute", 
                        top: "50%", 
                        left: "50%", 
                        marginLeft: -50, // Half the width of this child
                        marginTop: 70 // This just controls how far down from center this child is
                    }}>
                        <Text>...world</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
```

This does require you to know the size of the elements inside the parent however so you can correctly set the marginLeft and marginTop values on the children.